# vk api парсинг стран и городов

Tags: php, ajax, vkontakte-api, laravel

Предо мной, стояла задача интегрировать в сайт бд стран и городов. Прочел несколько статей и решил интегрировать с api в контакте. На локальном сервере все настроил, работает, а на удаленном данном сервере, данные не получает вот код:

```
$lang = 3;

$headerOptions = array(
  'http' => array(
      'method' => "GET",
      'header' => "Accept-language: en\r\n".
      "Cookie: remixlang=$lang\r\n"
   )
);

$methodUrl = 'http://api.vk.com/method/database.getCountries?v=5.5&need_all=0';
$streamContext = stream_context_create($headerOptions);
$json = file_get_contents($methodUrl, false, $streamContext);
$countries = json_decode($json, true);

return $countries;
```

Comment: Видимо у сервера отключена в настройках `allow_url_fopen` что не позволяет работать с обертками типа `curl` и `file_get_contents` и прочим

Comment: ``cURL`` будет работать и с ``allow_url_fopen=false``

Comment: @xEdelweiss Да, я наверное лишканул.......Перепишу-дополню.. Как правило, если хостер ограничивает работу с обертакми типа `file_get_contents`,  тогда скорее всего и одновременно запретит и `curl` в настройках сервака... такое любят делать на бесплатных хостах. только за плату... Как вариант - все же попробовать вариант с `curl`. Если удаленный сервак принадлежит ТС, то значит надо скорее всего лишь включить `allow_url_open`

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский  посмотрел в phpinfo, allow_url_fopen=on

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский allow_url_include стоит в off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

$data = [];

$countries = curl_init();

curl_setopt($countries, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.vk.com/method/database.getCountries');
curl_setopt($countries, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($countries, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'need_all=1&count=1000');
curl_setopt($countries, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$countries_res = json_decode(curl_exec($countries), 1);

curl_close($countries);

foreach ($countries['response'] as $country) {
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($countries, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.vk.com/method/database.getCountries');
    curl_setopt($countries, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($countries, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'count=1000&country_id=' . $country['cid']);
    curl_setopt($countries, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $cities = json_decode(curl_exec($c), 1);

    curl_close($c);

    $data[] = $cities['response'];
}

var_dump($data);
```

Comment: к сожалению, это тоже работает только на локальном сервере(

Comment: тогда я перепишу это на cUrl

Comment: @ValentineMurnik, теперь попробуйте. Должно работать. Если не работает - то пишите в техподжержку. Пусть Вам активируют `allow_fopen_url`

Comment: спасибо большое, этот вариант работает)

Comment: @ValentineMurnik, если надо будет помощь - обращяйтесь. Можете напрямую писать на почту - romanko95.rk@gmail.com . Отвечу

Comment: а у меня платный хост но при тесте вышла ошибка Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @privetsh, каким хостингом пользуетесь?

Comment: от shneider-host.ru